# Access Moodle (Gradebook) API with HTTP requests using the httr package in R

Tags: r, http, get, moodle, httr

I am new to the world of APIs and, as an `R` user, the current go-to package is the `httr` package. The package sends HTTP requests with the `GET()` function. My issue is that I would like to access the gradebook of my course on Moodle via [the gradebook API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Gradebook_API) and everything I find in the documentation makes use of PHP. Is there any way to access to access the API with HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use directly the internal Moodle API from another language. To talk with Moodle from R you should use Moodle Web Services.

See [Web Service functions](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions)

So you need to identify which one's do you need and configure your Moodle server to expose them as REST WS. Than any tool that can perform POST or GET can interact with it.

For configuration instructions see [Web services](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Web_services)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I teach at a university and I have a teacher account. Does it mean that I have to contact the people in charge here and ask them to perform the server configurations for me?

Comment: Yes. You need to speak with people that manage your Moodle instance.